# iron-pages: Page Changed Event

Tags: web, polymer

Is there any event that can be captured by a web component when the page is changed, or even a lifecycle callback?

I tried using the attached callback but it doesn't being fired again..

Comment: You mean when the browser goes to another page?

Comment: Yes, another page in my application using iron-page-selector

Comment: This one: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages ?

Comment: Exactly, this is the element

Comment: Ok. The element fires some events, as described on the documentation page. Have you tried that? Maybe you could show some code?

Comment: I'll share some code later on, it's good idea

Comment: After looking again in the code, there is nothing meaningful to share. It's just simple iron-pages element and inside an element that needs to capture when a page changes to listen again for events

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- From the parent element of `<iron-pages>`, you could [observe](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#change-callbacks) changes to [`<iron-pages>.selected`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#property-selected) to monitor the page index/name:

  ```html
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>

    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <iron-pages id="pages" selected="{{selected}}">
          <div>One</div>
          <div>Two</div>
          <div>Three</div>
        </iron-pages>
        <paper-button on-tap="_prev">Prev</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-tap="_next">Next</paper-button>
      </template>
      <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          Polymer({
            is: 'x-foo',
            properties : {
              selected: {
                type: Number,
                value: 0,
                observer: '_selectedChanged'
              }
            },
            _selectedChanged: function(newPage, oldPage) {
              console.log('<iron-pages>.selected', 'new', newPage, 'old', oldPage);
            },
            _prev: function() {
              this.$.pages.selectPrevious();
            },
            _next: function() {
              this.$.pages.selectNext();
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  ```

  <sup>[codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RZMadd?editors=1011)</sup>
- Or you could setup an [event listener](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#event-listeners) for the [`<iron-pages>.iron-select`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#event-iron-select) and [`<iron-pages>.iron-deselect`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#event-iron-deselect) events in order to watch the selected and deselected elements.

  ```html
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>

    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <iron-pages id="pages" selected="0"
                    on-iron-select="_pageSelected"
                    on-iron-deselect="_pageDeselected">
          <div>One</div>
          <div>Two</div>
          <div>Three</div>
        </iron-pages>
        <paper-button on-tap="_prev">Prev</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-tap="_next">Next</paper-button>
      </template>
      <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          Polymer({
            is: 'x-foo',
            _pageSelected: function(e) {
              var page = e.detail.item;
              console.log('page selected', page);
            },
            _pageDeselected: function(e) {
              var page = e.detail.item;
              console.log('page deselected', page);
            },
            _prev: function() {
              this.$.pages.selectPrevious();
            },
            _next: function() {
              this.$.pages.selectNext();
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  ```

  <sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rrvVRB?editors=1011)</sup>
- Or you could configure [`<iron-pages>.selectedAttribute`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#property-selectedAttribute) so that it sets an attribute on the newly and previously selected pages, which you could observe from within the page itself. When the page selection changes, the previously selected page's attribute is set to `false`, and the newly selected to `true`.

  ```html
  <head>
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.9.3/components/">
    <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-foo></x-foo>

    <dom-module id="x-foo">
      <template>
        <iron-pages id="pages" selected="0" selected-attribute="selected">
          <x-page data-name="p1">One</x-page>
          <x-page data-name="p2">Two</x-page>
          <x-page data-name="p3">Three</x-page>
        </iron-pages>
        <paper-button on-tap="_prev">Prev</paper-button>
        <paper-button on-tap="_next">Next</paper-button>
      </template>
      <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          Polymer({
            is: 'x-foo',
            _prev: function() {
              this.$.pages.selectPrevious();
            },
            _next: function() {
              this.$.pages.selectNext();
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
    
    <dom-module id="x-page">
      <template>
        <content id="content"></content>
      </template>
      <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
          Polymer({
            is: 'x-page',
            properties: {
              selected: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
                observer: '_selectedChanged'
              }
            },
            _selectedChanged: function(selected) {
              console.log('<x-page>.sel', this.dataset.name, selected);
            }
          });
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
  ```

  <sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/yajNkm?editors=1001)</sup>

Comment: I added `this.listen(this, 'iron-select', '_onIronSelect');` to my component `attached` callback but `_onIronSelect` is never being fired

Comment: I ended up using `this.listen(document, 'iron-select', '_onIronSelect')` and now everything works

Comment: Listening to the event at `document` level is not recommended. That might cause problems down the line if you ever add an element that uses `iron-selector` internally, as that also would fire `iron-select`, causing your handler to be invoked. Assuming `this` is the parent of `iron-pages`, you could assign an `id` to `iron-pages` (e.g., `id="pages"`), and then from the parent's `ready` callback, do: `this.listen(this.$.pages, 'iron-select', '_onIronSelect');`. Or you could use the annotated listener as seen in my code snippet above.

Comment: I'm building an open source component and I can't assume the user will follow this convention

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Which convention are you referring to?

Comment: To give the `iron-pages` an id, I don't want to force my users into doing that

Comment: You don't have to force your users to add an `id` (although I don't understand your hesitation in using `id`s). That's just one way of quickly referencing an element. Otherwise, they'd have to query for it. But your users could easily use an annotated event listener, avoiding the need for a reference to the `iron-pages`. In any case, if you recommend listening to the event at the `document` level, you're potentially setting your users up for undesired behavior.

Comment: Got it! I'll change this behavior to something else, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Yes there's the 'iron-select' event.  You can create a listener on an element and have it listen for this event.

'iron-activate' is triggered right before the item changes, if you prefer.

Here's the link to all the iron-pages events: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-pages#event-iron-activate

Comment: The `iron-items-changed` event doesn't fire when a new page is selected. http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rrvOrx?editors=1000